# Modify Breeze template in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working with [Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits) Template in Laravel. Here I altered HTML code

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
```

to Breeze Code

```
`<x-input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" />`.
```

But now how can I alter this HTML code

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option>1</option> 
    <option>2</option> 
    <option>3</option> 
    <option>4</option> 
    <option>5</option> 
 </select>
```

to Breeze Code ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably too late, but I faced the same problem. Surprisingly, there is not wrapper for `select` in **Breeze**.

So you can make your own wrapper like that:

Blade component (*resources/views/components/select.blade.php*):

```php
@props(['disabled' => false])

<select {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50']) !!}>
    {{ $slot }}
</select>
```

And use it this way:

```php
<x-select id="select" class="block w-full" name="field">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>{{ __('Choose an option') }}</option>

    <option value="1">Some</option>
    <option value="2">options</option>
    <option value="3">here</option>
</x-select>
```

Comment: add this classes for dark mode support: 

dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 dark:focus:border-indigo-600 dark:focus:ring-indigo-600

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what your looking for I guess !!

```
     <x-dropdown class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <xd-item>1</xd-item>
        <xd-item>2</xd-item>
      </x-dropdown>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rifkan Razak. I am facing this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RnIZ.png

Comment: Mark above answer right if its done and your new error you have to pass the $trigger variable to your blade from your controller

Comment: Thanks @Rifkan Razak. Isn't `$trigger` variable related to this `Dropdown` ? Thanks.

Comment: No I guess, Error says undefined Variable,  which means no such variable passed to that blade

Comment: Thanks @Rifkan Razak. If I remove these codes error will not produce. Could you please help me to solve the issue ? Thanks

Comment: Remove the {{ $trigger }} and just pass a static value and see first !

Comment: Thanks @Rifkan Razak. How did you get this code `<x-dropdown class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <xd-item>1</xd-item>
        <xd-item>2</xd-item>
      </x-dropdown>` ?

Comment: I couldn't solve the issue. Could you please help me in this regard ?